# Mapreduce output number of files in HDFS according to reduce task or reduce method call

Tags: java, mapreduce, hdfs

Just for learning I tried to modify the word count example and added a partiotiner. I understood the part that by writing the customized partiotiner we can control the number of Reduce Task so getting created. This is good.

But one question I am not able to understood is number of output files so generated in hdfs so that depends on number of Reduce Task so called or number of Reduce calls so done for each Reduce task.
(For each Reduce Task there can be many reduce calls happening).

Let me know if any other detail is needed. Code is very basic so not posting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your perception that writing the customized partitioner can control the number of Reduce Task getting created is wrong. Please check the following explanation:-

Actually paritioner determines in which reducer to send the key and list of values based of the hash value of the key as explained below.
`public class HashPartitioner<K, V> extends Partitioner<K, V> {
public int getPartition(K key, V value,
int numReduceTasks) {
return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
}
}`

Now the question of number of output files generated depends on the number of reduce task which you have asked the job to run. So in case say you configured 3 reduce task for the job, and say you wrote a custom partitioner which lead to sending the keys into only 2 reducers. In this case you will find empty part-r00002 output file for the third reducer as it did not get any records after partitioning. This empty part file can be removed using LazyOutputFormat.

Ex: `import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat;
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);`

I hope this clears your doubt.